# Cannot resolve symbol 'container' - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I just created a new projet, building some layouts, writing some code. Everything was fine except I got this error as shown in the picture below.

[image]

I tried to remove and type it again and when typing 'R.id.', there was no 'container' showing up in the list. So that means theres no problem with my R file, just that the 'container' word lost somewhere.

Those code above are actually default code in onCreate() method in your main activity everytime you create a new project in Android Studio. (I actually tried to create a new project to compare and yes it's the same, and without error as it's brand new.).

All I did was comment out the if statement block so the error goes away, and the application has run just fine on the emulator. I just don't know why I got that problem and how I can handle it as I may need to do that in the future. Thank you!

Edit after @Raghunandan has mentioned: Below is my xml.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/provide_information"
        android:id="@+id/provideInfoButton"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/take_picture"
        android:id="@+id/takePictureButton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/provideInfoButton"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/takePictureButton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/classNameTextView"
        android:layout_above="@+id/personNametextView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="44dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_marginBottom="38dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/emailTextView"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/emailTextView"
        android:id="@+id/personNameTextView" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/emailTextView"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/classNameTextView"
        android:layout_marginBottom="82dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/send_button"
        android:id="@+id/sendButton"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post your activity_main.xml

Comment: thanks man, I found out the reason! :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that I changed the root layout to RelativeLayout (the default of Android Studio was FrameLayout  which has an id of "container"). My bad :). Thanks for mentioning about posting the xml file. I have not noticed that as I'm not as familiar with Android Studio as with Eclipse yet.